# Vue prop item seems to be empty?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm attempting to write a todo app as my first ever Vue project. It seems it's not showing my items in the `TodoItem` component -- inside the `h3` tag.

I've double-checked everything but I just can't see anything wrong. Why are my items not appearing?

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Todos v-bind:todos="todos" message="Here are your daily tasks"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Todos from './components/Todos.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Todos
  },
  data: {

    todos: [
      {
        id: 1, 
        title: "Todo one",
        completed: false,
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        title: "Todo two",
        completed: false,
      },
      {
        id: 3, 
        title: "Todo three",
        completed: true,
      }
    ]

  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Todos:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <div v-bind:key="todo.id" v-for="todo in todos">
      <TodoItem v-bind:todo="todo" />
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import TodoItem from '../components/TodoItem.vue'

export default {
  name: "Landing",
  components: {
    TodoItem
  },
  props: ["message", "todos"],
  data: {
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

TodoItem:

```
<template>
  <div class="todo-item">
      <h3>ITEM: test</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "TodoItem",
  props: ["todo"],
  data: {
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` [must be a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) for a component. Your code renders the items if you make the following changes:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Todos,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Todo one',
          completed: false,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Todo two',
          completed: false,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Todo three',
          completed: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

I **highly** recommend integrating [eslint](https://eslint.org/) along with [eslint-plugin-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue) into your editor to avoid these kinds of common errors.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, `data` in a Vue component must be a function.

Here's a working version to help you out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ds5up?fontsize=14